# How to check if a string contains only white space or is empty in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a function that would handle white spaces or empty strings using TypeScript

I tried this function:

```
export const isEmpty = function(text: string): string {
  return text === null || text.match(/^ *$/) !== null;
};
```

but I get `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'`

What would be the best way to check if a string is empty or if it contains only white spaces and tabs using TypeScript?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error `Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'` is due to the function signature indicating that the return type is a `string` when it is actually returning a `boolean`.

The definition should be:

```
export const isEmpty = function(text: string): boolean {
  return text === null || text.match(/^ *$/) !== null;
};
```

### Whitespace Catch-All

Note that whitespace may be any of the following:

- space character
- tab character
- carriage return character
- new line character
- vertical tab character
- form feed character

To handle these cases, the regular expression should be:

```
/^\s*$/
```

The function could be written:

```
export function isEmpty(text: string): boolean {
  return text == null || text.match(/^\s*$/) !== null;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

No need of Regex.
Simply do

```
export const isEmpty = function(text: string): boolean{
  return (!text || text.trim() === "");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, simple way to check if the string only contains white spaces.

```
export function isEmpty(text: string): boolean {
    return !(text && text.length > 0 && text.trim().length > 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `boolean` but your function is expecting `string`, so change it as follows:

```
export const isEmpty = function(text: string): boolean {
  return text === null || text.match(/^ *$/) !== null;
};
```

You could also not set the expected return type and let the TypeScript compiler infer from the implementation that it is `boolean`:

```
export const isEmpty = function(text: string) {
  return text === null || text.match(/^ *$/) !== null;
};
```